# Performance discrepancies between itertools.product & list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, functional-programming, python-itertools

I was exploring Python's `itertools` module and came across the `itertools.product` function that returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`. I find it to be a really neat way of reducing nestings in complex `for-loops` where list comprehension might be inadequate. However, before proceeding, I wanted to check how it performs with the alternative methods. Here're a few tests that I conducted. Used Jupyter Notebook's built-in `%%timeit` to measure the performance.

#### case-1: vanilla list comprehension

```py
%%timeit -n 50 -r 5

[(x,y) for x in range(1000) if x%2==0 for y in range(1000) if y%2==1]
```

```
>>> 35.8 ms ± 1.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 50 loops each)
```

#### case-2: itertools.product in a list comprehension

Removed `itertools` import to avoid import time showing up here.

```py
%%timeit -n 50 -r 5

[(x,y) for (x,y) in itertools.product(range(1000), range(1000)) if x%2==0 and y%2==1]
```

```
>>> 62.1 ms ± 1.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 50 loops each)
```

#### case-3: vanilla nested for loop

```py
%%timeit -n 50 -r 5

lst = []
for x in range(1000):
    for y in range(1000):
       if x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 1:
           lst.append((x,y))
```

```
>>> 72 ms ± 769 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 50 loops each)
```

#### case-4: for loop with itertools.product

```py
%%timeit -n 50 -r 5

lst = []
for x, y in itertools.product(range(1000),range(1000)):
    if x%2==0 and y%2==1:
        lst.append((x,y))
```

```
>>> 74.5 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 50 loops each)
```

However, [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools) part of the documentation, I suppose, claims better performance than vanilla `for` loops. Also, shouldn't **case-2** be faster than **case-1**? In **case-3** and **case-4**, the performance difference gets worse for `itertools.product` as the sizes of the iterables increase. What is going on here? Also, please add a few examples where `itertools.product` might be a better candidate than listcomp or nested for loops.

Comment: case1 isn't a fair comparison to case 1, where you are filtering earlier, skipping the inner loop when not `x%2==0` so you aren't iterating over the whole product. Anyway, I don't see why you think case 3 and case 4 should be different. Their performance seems essentially the same which is what I would expect.

Comment: I suspect that the worse performance of `itertools.product` is due to it creating auxiliary lists which it needs to because it accepts *any iterable*, including iterators, which are single-pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing different things:

```
[(x,y) for x in range(1000) if x%2==0 for y in range(1000) if y%2==1]
```

...is not the same as

```
[(x,y) for x in range(1000) for y in range(1000) if x%2==0 and y%2==1]
```

The first one skips the second loop entirely if `x%2 != 0`, the second one loops through all `1000 ** 2 == 1,000,000` combinations. Cases 2 to 4 are in the same category as the second comprehension here, so they are inherently slower.

Comment: The first argument is clear. The two listcomps aren't the same. Missed the part when `%2!=0`. Thank you! However,  `case-3` and `case-4` are equivalent, right? And the doc says that in this case, the `itertools.product` should be faster, but it isn't.

Comment: @RedowanDelowar where, **exactly** in the docs does it claim this?

Comment: @RedowanDelowar, yep, where exactly does it say that?

Comment: It says `The module standardizes a core set of fast, memory efficient tools that are useful by themselves or in combination.`

I wanted to know where does it give you that extra speed? An example may be.

Comment: @RedowanDelowar, I don't see any _extra_ speed mentioned here. `itertools` is fast and memory efficient - but nowhere is it said that it's faster than raw loops.

Comment: Yes. There is no mention of that directly but I was looking for a concrete justification of using that instead of a nested loop (other than avoiding multiple levels of nestings).

Comment: @RedowanDelowar, for example, you can create `itertools`' iterators dynamically, but nested loops have to be written manually (you _can_ create them dynamically too, but it's more complicated than using `itertools`)